# Selecting multiple fields for Property Transfer in SoapUI

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, xpath, soapui

I am hoping that someone can help me using a Web Service with SoapUI?

I have created **TestSteps** to authenticate the user, do a search for data and then export that data into an Excel file.  The problem I am having is that I am only getting one row of data each time whereas I need the full 100 records that are provided in the XML Response file.

When I make the SOAP Request, the responding XML file contains fields of data within the **UID** tags that I want to extract:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
      <ns2:searchResponse xmlns:ns2="http://woksearch.v3.wokmws.thomsonreuters.com">
         <return>
             <queryId>1</queryId>
             <recordsFound>3648</recordsFound>
             <recordsSearched>38406647</recordsSearched>
             <records><records     xmlns="http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/wok5.4/public/Fields">
<REC r_id_disclaimer="ResearcherID data provided by Thomson Reuters">    <UID>WOS:A1993LC48100001</UID><static_data></static_data><dynamic_data><cluster_related>    </cluster_related></dynamic_data></REC>
<REC r_id_disclaimer="ResearcherID data provided by Thomson Reuters">    <UID>WOS:A1993LE28400012</UID><static_data></static_data><dynamic_data><cluster_related>    </cluster_related></dynamic_data></REC>
<REC r_id_disclaimer="ResearcherID data provided by Thomson Reuters">    <UID>WOS:000239231100002</UID><static_data></static_data><dynamic_data><cluster_related>    </cluster_related></dynamic_data></REC>
<REC r_id_disclaimer="ResearcherID data provided by Thomson Reuters">    <UID>WOS:000225797900011</UID><static_data></static_data><dynamic_data><cluster_related>    </cluster_related></dynamic_data></REC>
<REC r_id_disclaimer="ResearcherID data provided by Thomson Reuters">    <UID>WOS:000249142800001</UID><static_data></static_data><dynamic_data><cluster_related>    </cluster_related></dynamic_data></REC>
<REC r_id_disclaimer="ResearcherID data provided by Thomson Reuters">    <UID>WOS:000071234000001</UID><static_data></static_data><dynamic_data><cluster_related>    </cluster_related></dynamic_data></REC>
<REC r_id_disclaimer="ResearcherID data provided by Thomson Reuters">    <UID>WOS:000292046900004</UID><static_data></static_data><dynamic_data><cluster_related>    </cluster_related></dynamic_data></REC>
<REC r_id_disclaimer="ResearcherID data provided by Thomson Reuters">    <UID>WOS:A1992JR22700001</UID> ....etc.
```

I am trying to use a **Property Transfer** to take all these **UID** values as a list and insert them into another SOAP Request between **uid** tags.  The response to this SOAP Request will then give me detailed data about each record.

Unfortunately, whatever I try, it will only ever return and pass on one record rather than the full 100.

At the moment the XPath I have as the **Source** in **Property Transfer** is:

```
declare namespace     ns1='http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/wok5.4/public/Fields';
declare namespace ns2='http://woksearch.v3.wokmws.thomsonreuters.com';
//ns2:searchResponse[1]/return[1]/records[1]/ns1:records[1]/ns1:REC/ns1:UID[1]
```

Under the **records** tag, each **UID** value is stored in a separate **REC** tag, so I need to iterate through the **REC** tags, selecting the **UID** value each time.

The image below shows the hierarchical layout of the file and position of the **UID** values nested within the **REC** values:

*Turns out I can't post images because my reputation is too low!  The nesting is like this:

```
<searchResponse>
    <return>
        <records>
            <records>
                <REC>
                    <UID>WOS: DDKJ7898dIJH</UID>
                </REC>
                <REC>
                    <UID>WOS: OIJS897JBSSS</UID>
                </REC>
                etc...
```

Does anyone know how I can get all these values to pass into another SOAP Request?  I have tried a number of different XPath variations to no avail.  I also tried using a **DataSink** to pull all the **UID** values into a spreadsheet and then import them into the other request with **DataSource**, but I could still only transfer one value at a time!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you for your time,

John

Comment: What is the destination format? `<REC><UID>...</UID><UID>...</UID></REC>` ?

Comment: I'll be using the extracted UID values in another SOAP Request enclosed in <uid>...</uid> tags, i.e. <uid>WOS: DDKJ7898dIJH WOS: OIJS897JBSSS etc.</uid>

Comment: I added an answer. If it doesn't work there is another way with groovy scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that utilizes Property transfer would be (make sure to check XQuery):

```
declare namespace ns1='http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/wok5.4/public/Fields';
declare namespace ns2='http://woksearch.v3.wokmws.thomsonreuters.com';
<UID>
{
for $id in //ns1:UID 
return string($id)
}
</UID>
```

The output would be in the format:

```
<UID>WOS:A1993LC48100001 WOS:A1993LE28400012 WOS:000239231100002 WOS:000225797900011 WOS:000249142800001 WOS:000071234000001 WOS:000292046900004</UID>
```

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks very much for your help!  Have been trying to sort this for ages, thought of using XQuery but never used it before so wasn't sure how.  I don't suppose you could help me with one last thing?  I've passed these uid strings into a Soap Response and have got the data out from the response that I was after.  I am extracting the data from the Soap Response using the same iterating method you posted but with the relevant tags for the data (<title>, <full_name> etc.) but when I DataSink this into an Excel spreadsheet (my ultimate goal) it puts all the data for each tag..

Comment: ..into a single cell.  E.g. all 100 'Journal Title's into a single cell in the worksheet.  How would I split the data back up so that each element is in its own cell?  Would this be something I'd do in the Property Transfer between the Soap Response and DataSink or something I'd specify in the DataSink itself?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach goes like this:

1. Make your first call to retrieve all the UIDs.
2. Create a DataSource with type = XML to extract all the UIDs.
3. Dynamically create your second call (in step 5 below). See [my blog post](http://siking.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/dynamically-create-elements-in-a-soapui-request/) for hints how to accomplish this.
4. Loop over all the values in step 2.
5. Make your second call.